# Print remaining lines in file after regular expression that includes variable

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk, ksh

I have the following data:

> ====> START LOG for Background Process: HRBkg Hello on 2013/09/27 23:20:20 Log Level 3
>  09/27 23:20:20 I Background process is using
>   processing model #: 3
>  09/27 23:20:23 I
>  09/27 23:20:23 I --
>   Started Import for External Key
>   ====> START LOG for Background Process: HRBkg Hello on 2013/09/30 07:31:07 Log Level 3
>  09/30 07:31:07 I Background process is using
>   processing model #: 3
>  09/30 07:31:09 I
>  09/30 07:31:09 I --
>   Started Import for External Key

I need to extract the remaining file contents after the LAST match of **`====> START LOG`.....**
I have tried numerous times to use `sed`/`awk`, however, I can not seem to get `awk` to utilize a variable in my regular expression.  The variable I was trying to include was for the date (2013/09/30) since that is what makes the line unique.
I am on an `HP-UX` machine and can not use `grep -A`.

Any advice?

Comment: Here is the data without the wrapping:

Comment: You can't format text in a comment and update your question to show what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to test for a specific time just to find the last entry in the file:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ }
    NR == FNR { if (/START LOG/) lastMatch=NR; next }
    FNR == lastMatch { found=1 }
    found
' file
```

Comment: Is the behaviour of the assignment in the BEGIN block defined?  It is not in C (you can't tell which value of ARGC will be used on the RHS).  It is a little dangerous and could be written more safely: `ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++`.

Comment: What I had (`ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[ARGC-1]`) is implementation-dependent according to the bottom section of gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Increment-Ops.html so I updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
a=2013/09/30
sed '\|START LOG.*'"$a"'|{h;d};H;$!d;x' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return your desired output.

```
sed -n '/START LOG/h;/START LOG/!H;$!b;x;p' file
```

If you have `tac` available, you could easily do..

```
tac <file> | sed '/START LOG/q' | tac
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, re

for fn in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(fn) as f:
        m=re.search(r'.*(^====> START LOG.*)',f.read(), re.S | re.M)
        if m:
            print m.group(1)
```

Then run:

```
$ ./re.py /tmp/log.txt
====> START LOG for Background Process: HRBkg Hello on 2013/09/30 07:31:07 Log Level 3
09/30 07:31:07 I Background process is using processing model #: 3
09/30 07:31:09 I
09/30 07:31:09 I -- Started Import for External Key
```

If you want to exclude the `====> START LOGS..` bit, change the regex to:

`r'.*(?:^====> START LOG.*?$\n)(.*)'`

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you can easily match a variable against a regular expression in Awk, or vice versa.

```
awk -v date='2013/09/30' '$0 ~ date {p=1} p' file
```

This sets `p` to 1 if the input line matches the date, and prints if `p` is non-zero.

(Recall that the general form in Awk is *condition* `{` *actions* `}` where the block of actions is optional; if omitted, the default action is to print the current input line.)

Comment: You only search for `date`, not for the `START LOG`, what if there are several line from the same `date`?

Answer (score 0):

This prints the last `START LOG`, it set a flag for the last block and print it.

```
awk 'FNR==NR  { if ($0~/^====> START LOG/) f=NR;next} FNR>=f' file file
```

You can use a variable, but if you have another file with another date, you need to know the date in advance.

```
var="2013/09/30"
awk '$0~v && /^====> START LOG/ {f=1}f' v="$var" file
====> START LOG for Background Process: HRBkg Hello on 2013/09/30 07:31:07 Log Level 3
09/30 07:31:07 I Background process is using processing model #: 3
09/30 07:31:09 I
09/30 07:31:09 I -- Started Import for External Key
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer in perl:

If your logs are in assume `filelog.txt`.

```perl
my @line;

open (LOG, "<filelog.txt") or "die could not open filelog.tx";

while(<LOG>) {
   @line = $_;
}

my $lengthline = $#line;
my @newarray;
my $j=0;

for(my $i= $lengthline ; $i >= 0 ; $i++) {
  @newarray[$j] = $line[$i];
  if($line[$i] =~ m/^====> START LOG.*/) {
    last;
  }
  $j++;
}

print "@newarray \n";
```

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk (`gawk`) or Mikes awk (`mawk`) you can set the record separator (`RS`) so that each record will contain a whole log message. So all you need to do is print the last one in the `END` block:

```
awk 'END { printf "%s", RS $0 }' RS='====> START LOG' infile
```

Output:

```
====> START LOG for Background Process: HRBkg Hello on 2013/09/30 07:31:07 Log Level 3
09/30 07:31:07 I Background process is using processing model #: 3
09/30 07:31:09 I
09/30 07:31:09 I -- Started Import for External Key
```